# CSS Floating divs but keeping min-height

Tags: css, html

I need to float 2 divs #left to left side #right to right side but when I do this my #hold for left and right doesn't extend (its set with min-height).

Is there any way I can float 2 divs side by side but keeping them extending the min-height?

I have tried: display:inline-block; but its a mess to sort with IE. I have also tried `position:relative` and `position:absolute`.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS code?

Answer (score 3):

Simple fix sorry for inconvenience, if anyone else is having the same problem just add `overflow: hidden;` to your #hold div.

Thanks to this post:
[How do I keep two divs that are side by side the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and understand your vague description, i think this is what you meant:

http://jsfiddle.net/QT6jS/8/

the solution is to add another div at the bottom of all floats, that clears all.
The min-height won't folllow a float, but will follow a div with clear:both;

```
    <div class="parent_expander" style="clear:both;"></div>
```

this will get you the following result:

http://jsfiddle.net/QT6jS/9/

Comment: This answered my question. Man...having a div that will always encapsulate its floating children was a huge headache for me. Thanks for this answer @CRutgerX

Answer (score 0):

A basic example of the situation you describe works with no issue.

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">Something</div>
<div class="test">Something</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test{
    float: left;
    min-height:100px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/QT6jS/