# Make two divs side by side, one is resizable and the other has same height

Tags: css, html

I bring here a drama with css height.

I would like to make a layout, a div that contains 2 divs both in same line, one is resizable and the other must fit in the parent's height (same height as the first one).

The first div can have additional information (so i **can't fix the height**), so it will have more lines, the important is that it must not have a scroll bar. The second div must obey the first height, if it's bigger than it will have a scroll bar.

[image]

```
<div class='container'> <!-- parent -->
    <div class='left'> <!-- resizable -->
    </div>
    <div class='right'> <!-- same height as left div  -->
    </div>
</div>
```

[UNSOLVED CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/mgrPG/2/)

The problem is that i can't figure out how to make it just using css. Or even it's possible just with css. I would not like to use js.

Someone please help me!

Comment: What do you mean by resizable?

Comment: *The problem is that i can figure out how to make it just using css.* <- so, where is the problem?

Comment: @Mr.Alien I think OP meant *of varying heights*.

Comment: Perhaps he mean `I can't` :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I keep two divs that are side by side the same height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height)

Comment: the first div may increase/decrease height with some ajax code, or even the width is fixed, and if a line is too big, it must break the word, making more lines

Comment: thanks for noticing Hjpotter.

Comment: It's not a duplicated post

Comment: @korogui [Here's another solution](http://jsbin.com/uyazip/1/edit) you might want to consider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MsgrF/)

What you do is make the right one `absolutely positioned` which stops its height influencing the parent's.

**RELEVANT CSS**

```css
.container {
    background-color: gray;
    display: table;
    width: 70%;
    position:relative;
}

.container .left{
    background-color: tomato;
    width: 35%;
}

.container .right{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:35%;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 65%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Note that for this to work the parent must also be non-static (in this case `relative`).

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks :) YLSNED. Either way, I doubt OP wants it to be static (its not in his fiddle regardless).