# Bootstrap Box Spanning with div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I want to divide the web page area like the pic shown. I have tried this approach. To some extent it is right. Would appreciate to clear my doubts.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
       <div class="well">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12"><div class="well">canvas</div></div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-8"><div class="well">edit text</div></div>
               <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well">Button</div></div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well" >Control panel</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of Bootstrap you are using and what is the problem with your current approach? Also do you want it to be responsive?

Comment: Also please fix indents in your HTML. Its very hard to follow and may even contain some hanging tags.

Comment: its V3.1.1 and yes i want the page to be responsive

Comment: no its not working. Can you please tell me where i am making the mistake?

Comment: First, fix your HTML markup. You still have like 4 unclosed div tags and I don't know where you want them closed. Then we can debug further.

Comment: can you upload your code to http://jsfiddle.net so we can see the problem?

Comment: hi @jsalonen i have fixed HTML tags. Can u help now

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem with this code? because your code is as per your requirement.

Comment: Well it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/406/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I tried in jsfiddle and is working for me (without the well class)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-8">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-xs-12">
                      Canvas
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-xs-8">Edit Text</div>
                 <div class="col-xs-4">Button</div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-4">Control panel</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aJ9ne/

Comment: well its the same way that i have written also. But do i adjust the height of the section called "Control Panel"?

Comment: See the update jsfiddle link. I have taken up the solution to adjust the height of "control panel" and make it same as that of left column from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height

Answer (score 1):

Try out this one.. it will work fine...

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="well">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"><div class="well">canvas</div></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8"><div class="well">edit text</div></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well">Button</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
<div class="col-md-4"><div class="well">Control panel</div></div></div>
```

Comment: no, it is not working properly. The right side column is coming half way. see my edited question for screenshot