# Remove space between side by side divs

Tags: html, css

I have created a `div` that allows people to select a section name and it will display the appropriate image, with a caption. I am having some trouble getting the section list and the image to display exactly side by side and have both take up the same height. Also, my picture caption (`figcaption`) does not obey the `figure` width, but I may just be overlooking that. I have tried many different combinations of `float`, `overflow`, `display` property tweaks as suggested by other Stackoverflow question answers, but none of them seem to produce the correct output.

Here is a JSFiddle of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/8We2Y/

The code is also included the code here.

**CSS:**

```
#main {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.gamemode {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 19px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
}

.gamemode:hover {
    background: #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #0093dd;
}

.gamemode:selected {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #0093dd;
}

#gm-text {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#gm-image {
    width: 74.5%;
    height: 556px;
    background: url(images/survivalimg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
}

figcaption { 
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 415px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

figcaption p {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #FFF;
}

#captitle { 
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

If you look at the CSS, you will notice that my width's for the two items are set to 25% and 74.5%, which doesn't add up to the full 100%. If I were to set the one to 75%, it just moves to a new line.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="showcase">
        <div id="gm-text">
            <p class="gamemode" id="survival" onclick="changeImageSurvival();"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Survival</p>
            <p class="gamemode" id="creative" onclick="changeImageCreative();"><i class="fa fa-building"></i> Creative</p>
            <p class="gamemode" id="sg" onclick="changeImageSG();"><i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i> Survival Games</p>
            <p class="gamemode" id="factions" onclick="changeImageFactions();"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> Factions</p>
            <p class="gamemode" id="kitpvp" onclick="changeImageKitPvP();"><i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i> KitPvP</p>
            <p class="gamemode" id="ctf" onclick="changeImageCTF();"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i> Capture the Flag</p>
            <p class="gamemode" id="spleef" onclick="changeImageSpleef();"><i class="fa fa-spoon"></i> Spleef</p>
        </div>
        <div id="gm-image">
             <figure>
                <figcaption>
                    <p id="captitle">Section 1</p>
                    <p id="caption">Section one info.</p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see here http://jsfiddle.net/T9GQ7/

```
#gm-text {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    clear: both;
    float:left;   /*here */
}
#gm-image {
    width: 75%;
    height: 556px;
    background: url(http://www.wallsave.com/wallpapers/1024x768/red-/22118/red-background-desktop-backgrounds-22118.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an annoying inline-block issue. One way to solve it is to set

```
font-size:0;
```

on the container element. Of course, you will have to state the desired font size on every child element that contains text. If you don't, the font-size: 0 property will hide any text.

Updated JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7fG3E/

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the space between the divs since it is inline-block.
Change this,

```
    <div id="gm-text">
   </div>
    <div id="gm-image">
```

To

```
<div id="gm-text">

</div><div id="gm-image">
```

Or

```
<div id="gm-text">

</div><!--
--><div id="gm-image">
```

That way you can keep your width 25% and 75%.
For same height issue, see related question.
[How do I keep two divs that are side by side the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height)