# Side by side boxes at 50%, but wanting to put fixed-sized boxes to keep in the center of each?

Tags: css, width, box

I'm trying to do is have two boxes, side-by-side, that stay at 50% of the screen width each so that they stay at 50% regardless of the screen width.

However, I'm also trying to put boxes with text inside each of those boxes, but I want the inside boxes completely centered and to remain at a fixed width so that the text doesn't shift around as the screen width changes.

Anyone have any ideas?  Seems like a simple thing, but I'm just getting started in CSS, so bear with me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS this way:

```
   .half-screen{
       box-sizing: border-box;
       display: inline-block;
       width: 50%
    }
```

And then you do your logic inside those box

Note that you can use `vertical-align: top;` if you want them to be side by side and have the same starting point

Answer (score 0):

```
#sides {
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
background-color: white;
}

#leftside {
width: 50%;
background-color: grey;
padding: 20px;
margin: 0px;
position: relative;
}

#rightside {
width: 50%;
display: inline-table;
background-color: #018DCA;
float: left;
padding: 20px;
margin-left: 50%;
position: relative;
}
```

.
.
.

```
<div id="sides">
<div id="leftside">
<h1>text</h1>
<p>
<h2>text</h2>
<br>
</div>
<div id="rightside">
<h1>text</h1>
<p>
<h2>text</h2>
<br>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A fixed size in the center of two side-by-side boxes:

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-size: 0;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px #222;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.subbox {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: indianred;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">
    <div class="centered subbox">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box box2">
    <div class="centered subbox">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow...thanks!  Man, there's a lot I have to learn...holy smokes.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Okay...now I have another issue...maybe you can help.  I have text of uneven lengths that I'm putting into each subbox; let's say a sentence in one box and a paragraph in the other.  I'd like BOTH box1 and box2 to stretch vertically to accommodate the longer text so that those boxes stay the same length.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @DrewK – Already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height