# Bootstrap column stacking

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, css-float

Is is possible to force a bootstrap column to force all columns to make use of the white space above?
Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/tkrhkz0d/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">A<br/>A</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">B</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C<br/>C</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">D</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">E<br/>E</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">F</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">G<br/>G</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">H</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">I<br/>I</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">J</div>
</div>
```

I want all whitespace to be filled without knowing the contents of the columns

[image]

Comment: Unclear as in what you trying to achieve. The fiddle is also different from the image shown

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height

Comment: I am sorry, I dont want equal heights. I want (for example) column 'D' to go up and take up the whitespace created beneath 'AA' and next to 'CC' without changing the order of the columns

Comment: i dont think its possible but you can wrap the big elements in one colm and other in one colm ?

Answer (score 0):

just change `background` from `col-sm-6` to `row`!

```
.row {
  background: #DDDDDD;
}
```

**EDIT**
in this case use bootstrap `row` for each couple of `cols`

[jsfiddle-link](http://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/tkrhkz0d/3/)

Comment: i don't care about the background. What i want to do is move up the columns to remove whitespace.

Comment: Now that I understand what you are trying to do : Take a look at masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/)