# Woocommerce: Align smaller images

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce crops my larger images neatly into dimensions that fit, but smaller images have no need to be cropped.

When I add an image which is too small, the product or product category won't align anymore. (https://do-it-creatief.nl/product-categorie/brei-haak-katoenwol/)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep two divs that are side by side the same height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve in two way:

1. Add large image or create large image using photoshop using white frame if you actual image is smaller.
2. Add css(You image will be so ugly): `.woocommerce ul.products li.product a img{ min-height: 210px;}`

***2nd option is really bad practice***

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The first option is more of a hack than a solution and as you have stated the second option is really bad practice. I can't believe there isn't a fix that dynamically adds margin for example.