# manage space between divs (dynamic height, float left)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple dynamic left aligned divs in my page, since the divs are dynamic so the heights will be different. I want to manage the empty space between divs . please tell me how to do it with css or javascript.
Please see below image (it is just for explanation)

[image]

Comment: where last block will go then ??

Comment: to the next row..

Comment: What is the problem you have for doing this with Javascript? Given that Javascript (differently from CSS) can do **literally** anything you want with the page seems to me the problem is just that you don't known what you want to do...

Comment: if you don't know the heights beforehand you can use something like `masonry.js`

Comment: Helpfully! check it!

http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html

Comment: It's an interesting question. You can design with negative value of `margin-bottom` and positive value of  `margin-top` depends on the heights of each item.

Comment: You can check this issue, might be get solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height

Comment: You can check the issue and might be get solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Masonry layout. Try to look at flexbox or column layout. Here are some examples:

- https://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/
- https://medium.com/@_jh3y/how-to-pure-css-masonry-layouts-a8ede07ba31a#.z9kxauh63

Answer (score 1):

One way is: You can do three column and add every third div per column.

Second way is: 'Masonry.js', that i use often. http://masonry.desandro.com/
its easy so i recomend it:

Html:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">...</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">...</div>
  <div class="grid-item">...</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.grid-item { width: 200px; }
.grid-item--width2 { width: 400px; }
```

jquery:

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 200
});
```