# Image dynamic height, relative to a div next to it

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs side by side. The first div contains text. The height of this div can vary, depending on how much text it contains.

The second div contains an image.

I would like the image to be the same height as the first div.

Is there a way to do that in css ?

I use bootstrap grid system. Both divs have the col-md-6 class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep two divs that are side by side the same height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height)

Comment: Check this link for demo https://jsfiddle.net/tejaspatil6191/1u5gxvbg/1/

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work exactly how I want. If I delete half the text in your example, the image's height will be bigger that the text-div.