# Trying to float two div but having issues

Tags: html, css

I tried aligning two divs in a single line. Used float left property and everything went good. But when I used images inside the div then it started creating issue.

So here is my example code:-

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child-left">
        <span>Some heading</span><br>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYeyz.png" />
   </div>
   <div class="child-right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ante nisi, cursus mattis lectus vel, tempor viverra enim. Duis finibus ultricies elit, eget convallis ligula sollicitudin ut. Aliquam in lorem vitae sem egestas tempor sit amet in ipsum. Duis sed turpis vestibulum, venenatis felis sed, pharetra nibh. Sed tempor, dui ac laoreet feugiat, purus velit auctor lorem, ac varius nisl mauris sit amet dui. Sed ut dapibus urna. Cras et sem eu arcu laoreet mollis.
    </div>
    <div class="child-left">
        <span>Some heading</span><br>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYeyz.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="child-right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ante nisi, cursus mattis lectus vel, tempor viverra enim. Duis finibus ultricies elit, eget convallis ligula sollicitudin ut. 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
width: 100%; }

.child-left {
float: left;
width: 30%; }

.child-right {
width: 70%;
float: left; }
```

So as you can see it's overlapping because the height of text area is not same as image height. Min-height property is not a good solution as I tried that.
So far I'm using table but this is not the best solution too. So what are my options?

Comment: Are you aware that `.child-right` is set to `float: left`?

Comment: Yeah, it there any issue with that?

Comment: Well if you want it to be on the right of your `div` then probably. I'm trying to gauge what exactly you're going for. Do you want to align them beside each other or above/below one another?

Comment: Trying to align in single line not vertically but horizontally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep two divs that are side by side the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css class:

```
img{width:100%;}
.child-left:nth-child(odd){clear:left;}
```

Here example

```css
.parent {
width: 100%; }

.child-left {
float: left;
width: 30%; }

.child-right {
width: 70%;
float: left; }
img{width:100%;}
.child-left:nth-child(odd){clear:left;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child-left">
        <span>Some heading</span><br>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYeyz.png" />
   </div>
   <div class="child-right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ante nisi, cursus mattis lectus vel, tempor viverra enim. Duis finibus ultricies elit, eget convallis ligula sollicitudin ut. Aliquam in lorem vitae sem egestas tempor sit amet in ipsum. Duis sed turpis vestibulum, venenatis felis sed, pharetra nibh. Sed tempor, dui ac laoreet feugiat, purus velit auctor lorem, ac varius nisl mauris sit amet dui. Sed ut dapibus urna. Cras et sem eu arcu laoreet mollis.
    </div>
    <div class="child-left">
        <span>Some heading</span><br>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYeyz.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="child-right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ante nisi, cursus mattis lectus vel, tempor viverra enim. Duis finibus ultricies elit, eget convallis ligula sollicitudin ut. 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! 
I'm still learning and if you can provide me some more information or any help link about this property then it would be of great help.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clear:both` after showing two div in single line. Check snippet.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.child-left {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

.child-right {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}

#clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-left">
    <span>Some heading</span>
    <br>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYeyz.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="child-right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ante nisi, cursus mattis lectus vel, tempor viverra enim. Duis finibus ultricies elit, eget convallis ligula sollicitudin ut. Aliquam in lorem vitae sem egestas tempor sit amet in ipsum.
    Duis sed turpis vestibulum, venenatis felis sed, pharetra nibh. Sed tempor, dui ac laoreet feugiat, purus velit auctor lorem, ac varius nisl mauris sit amet dui. Sed ut dapibus urna. Cras et sem eu arcu laoreet mollis.
  </div>
  <div id="clear"></div>
  <div class="child-left">
    <span>Some heading</span>
    <br>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYeyz.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="child-right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ante nisi, cursus mattis lectus vel, tempor viverra enim. Duis finibus ultricies elit, eget convallis ligula sollicitudin ut.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, though I got my answer already. Thanks for giving additional information. :)

Comment: @SumantSingh If you feel the answer is correct you can up vote to help others.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to clear the floats after each pair.
Use this CSS to make it works:

```
.child-right:after {
   display: block;
   content: '.';
   height: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-indent: -9999px;
}
```