# HTML/CSS: Flexbox not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20669539/7525350), I wanted to implement sidenotes on a blog using a CSS flex box. I ended up with this HTML code:

```css
article {
  width: 66%;
}

aside {
  width: 33%;
}

.lfloat {
  flex: 1;
  float: left;
}

.rfloat {
  flex: 1;
  float: right;
}

.pwn {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </p>

  <p class="pwn">
    <article class="lfloat">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </article>

    <aside class="rfloat">
      This is just a small comment
    </aside>
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </p>
</section>
```

Instead of getting a sidenote with the same height, [safari](https://ibb.co/cyTwrv) begins the next paragraph directly under the sidenote, adjacent to the other paragraph. [Vivaldi](https://ibb.co/fdBGrv) does even quirkier by moving the "L" before sidenote and resuming the next line with "orem ipsum...".
(Links are pictures of the rendered output by both browsers)

Questions:

- Is my code bad or is the feature implementation of the browsers causing me this issue?
- How could I fix the issue, so that it renders robustly at least on FF, Safari and anything built on top of chromium?

Comment: The `<p>` tag should be used to represent a single paragraph of text. It should not contain `<aside>` or `<article>` tags. Chrome actually moves these tags outside of the `<p>` which is probably why you don't see the results you are expecting

Comment: you may have to use `display:-webkit-flex;` https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox . Try it out

Comment: @Turnip Ok, so what is your suggestion to implement a bicolumnar design for sidenotes? Is it ok to use `<div>` inside `<p>` or would it break as well?

Comment: Why use a p at all? Why cant you use a div?

Comment: I can, and I do as it obviously helps, thanks a lot. Although I would have liked <p> a bit more, because it just simplifies it for myself to have things consistent and use semantic tags whenever I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you should use, `<div>` or `<span>`

As per turnip's comments `<p>` will represent a single paragraph of text

```css
article {
  width: 66%;
}

aside {
  width: 33%;
}

.lfloat {
  flex: 2;
  float: left;
}

.rfloat {
  flex: 1;
  float: right;
}

.pwn {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </p>

  <span class="pwn">
    <article class="lfloat">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </article>

    <aside class="rfloat">
      This is just a small comment
    </aside>
  </span>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </p>
</section>
```

**EDIT**

here you can do like this just change this

```
.lfloat {
  flex: 2;
  float: left;
}
```

`flex: 1` to `flex: 2`

Hope this will helps you

Comment: Thank you very much! It works like a charm for getting these things the same height. Unfortunately it broke my `width: 33%` and `width: 66%` specifications. Both now occupy 50% of the container. Same behaviour, no matter if I wrap in `<div>` or `<span>`.