# How to fill parent height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.solid_color{
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <div class="solid_color col-xs-3"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
      " <span>A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone</span> "
      <i>(Quote from someone)</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently `div.solid_color` is a line. It should have a height the same as neighbor element's height. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space) and a multitude of same answers found by searching SO.

Comment: @RacilHilan Well I cannot define any specific height for the parent, since the length of that sentence is dynamic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep two divs that are side by side the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height)

Comment: Note that to use bootstrap you are missing a wrapping div with container class, and for each row a div with the "row" class (around the col-xx-n divs) .

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  /* reason: "align-items: stretch" which makes flex-items of equal height by default, obviously they all take the height of the "tallest" one */
}

.solid_color {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="solid_color col-xs-3"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    " <span>A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone</span> "
    <i>(Quote from someone)</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this via JS just with selectors and finding the desired height with `getBoundingClientRect`.

```js
var height = document.querySelector('.col-xs-9').getBoundingClientRect().height;
document.querySelector('.solid_color').style.height = height + 'px';
```

```css
.solid_color{
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <div class="solid_color col-xs-3"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
      " <span>A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone</span> "
      <i>(Quote from someone)</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The result is correct (as expected). Thank you, upvopte. Just isn't there any approach to do that by pure CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: flex;` in your parent container and remove `height: 100%;` from the child div.

```css
.solid_color{
  background-color: gray;
}
.myparent{
 display: flex;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="myparent">
  <div class="solid_color col-xs-3"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
      " <span>A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone</span> "
      <i>(Quote from someone)</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I would give the div with the background color a position absolute and push over the div with the text with some margin. See code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
            <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
        <style>
            .solid_color {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 25%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: gray;
            }
            .outer {
                position: relative;
                float: left;
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .right-text {
                margin-left: 25%;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer">
        <div class="solid_color col-xs-3"></div>
        <div class="right-text col-xs-9">
            " <span>A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone A sentence from someone</span> "
            <i>(Quote from someone)</i>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```