# height of div 1(master page div) should equals to height of div 2(Content page div)

Tags: html, css

I have one div (**left navigation menu**) in master page & another div on the content page. I want the height of Master page div to increase dynamically as per the height of the content page. (The end user will put data in content page we don't know the exact height now of content page div).

I have tried height:100%, height:auto but it is not working.

```
enter code here

leftnavigation { width: 90%; 
height: 100%; /*overflow: hidden;*/ 
background-color: #E5E7E9; 
margin-left: -15px; 
color: white; }
```

Comment: Where is the code you have tried?

Comment: Just create a container around it with height auto, it'll size according to whichever is the bigger item; menu or content and shrink or grow the other with it.

Comment: @zgood 
        .leftnavigation {
            width: 90%;
            height: 100%;
            /*overflow: hidden;*/
            background-color: #E5E7E9;
            margin-left: -15px;
            color: white;
        }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep two divs that are side by side the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height)

Comment: @AliSheikhpour  i got the soluton for same page div but i am not getting for master page & on content page

Comment: Your markup is to be contained in the question itself and not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by applying `Display:Flex` property on bootstap **Row** Class & on `Class:col-md-3`