# Made aside same height as body

Tags: html, css, viewport-units

I would like to know how I can make the `<aside>` height the same height as `body`, even if it scrolls. The last try I did the body is always full height but the aside not. Please help me :)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: auto;
}

aside.sidebar {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}

aside.sidebar ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>tag 1</li>
    <li>tag 2</li>
    <li>tag 3</li>
    <!-- some li tags -->
  </ul>
</aside>
<main>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  <!-- some content -->
</main>
```

Comment: This question has been asked an hour ago already. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066066/how-to-make-my-side-bar-same-height-as-my-content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make my side bar same height as my content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066066/how-to-make-my-side-bar-same-height-as-my-content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use flexbox. All flex items of a flex parent will stretch to match the parent element's height.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgray;
  min-height: 2000px;
}

aside {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <!-- some li tags -->
  </ul>
</aside>
<main>
  <!-- some content -->
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `height:auto` on html and body, set it to 100%

Comment: I've already use it, but the aside still not same height as body