# How to match height of borders?

Tags: css

I would like to have the height of the right borders of several `div` blocks to match. The blocks contain different number of lines of text.

As you can see, the right borders don't match in height:

```css
.options {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-right: 1px #d0d2d3 solid;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.list {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<html>

<div class="list">
  <div class="options">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    long text
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    long long text
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know how that can be done?

Comment: See this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-side-by-side-divs-the-same-height

Comment: @MorShemesh But if I have `display: flex`, the text won't be vertically aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: table-cell;`

```
.options { 
    ...
    display: table-cell;
}
```