# How to make two block with the same height?

Tags: css

There is container:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="block1"></div>
   <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

Block `class="container"` has height of screen height.

How to make the same height for `block1, block2`? so that they occupy the entire height of the parent?

I have tried flex

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-side-by-side-divs-the-same-height

Comment: *I have tried flex* Can you show us your attempt ? I can't think of a much more easier way to achieve this than flex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grid can help you here without even setting an `height` which can be optionnal , mind `box-sizing` if `height`,  `border`s and `padding`s are involved:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);/* the keyword for the value : 1fr */
}

.container>div {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block1">give<br>me<br>some<br>heights</div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

usefull link to know more about it https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

flex would be for te browser's height:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.container>div {
  flex: 1;
  border: solid;
  margin: 2px;
  /* possible*/
}


/* reset */

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time [deleting my comments]

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex to get this done. You could also use float and set the height of the blocks to 100% and the widths of them to 50%.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 4px red solid;
}

.block1, .block2 {
  height: 50%;
}

.block1 {
  border: 4px green solid;
}

.block2 {
  border: 4px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="block1"></div>
   <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need block after block not inline, 50% by height

Comment: @OPV Apologies, I didn't understand your question. I've updated my answer to address this clarification.

Comment: instead height: 50%, i would use flex:1 , so no need to mind border/padding/margins