# How do I make this nav bar have the right height?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm trying to get this `div` to show up as the proper `height` (without manually setting the `height` to a fixed number such as `75px`).

So that it looks like:

```
------------------------------------------
| something | something else             |
------------------------------------------
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2fLr6enx/

I use `float` on the left `div`, so that it will always pull left and have the left `div` and right `div` on the same line (even if the right `div` is a very large image).

This, however, can make the `div` container smaller in `height` than the left `div` (it matches the `height` of the container to the right `div`)

I have tried to make this work with `inline-block`, `table-cell`, and other `css`, however cannot get it to work where they are both definitively on one line, and the `height` of the container contains both of them.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I keep two side-by-side divs the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-side-by-side-divs-the-same-height)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-side-by-side-divs-the-same-height

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox are wonderful for this kind of issues.
Just replace your

```
.container {
   ...
   display: block;
   ...
}
```

with

```
.container {
   ...
   display: flex;
   ...
}
```

Comment: doesn't flex have limited functionality on browsers that would cause issues depending on their phone or browser?

Comment: As far as I know, `flexboxes` are fully supported by every browsers now.
Check this out for more details : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex