# How to make the Button and TextField pitch perfect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make a form using `Material UI` and `React`. This is what I have so far:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Button, TextField} from '@material-ui/core'
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class AddItem extends React.Component {

    state = {
        text: ''
    }

    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({text: e.target.value})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit(this.state.text)}>
                <TextField id="task" label="Task" placeholder="e.g. Feed the fish" value={this.state.text}
                           onChange={this.handleChange} color="secondary" variant="outlined" size="small"/>
                <Button color="secondary" variant="outlined" endIcon={<AddIcon/>} size="large">
                    Add
                </Button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

AddItem.propTypes = {
    onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default AddItem
```

The result is the following screenshot:

[image]

But wait! Can you see that? The `Button` height and the `TextField` height are just so slightly misaligned! (By 2.5px I think). Is there any way to fix this?

This is better than earlier, where the TextField was a lot bigger than the Button (my fix was `size="small"` on the TextField).

**How can I make sure that the TextField and the Button are the same height?**

I know that in Bulma there's something like a `level` component that helps out with that, so is there any similar solution in `Material UI`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-side-by-side-divs-the-same-height

Comment: @keikai I was actually wondering whether there was any solution specific to Material UI, but if I can't find one, then I'll use the question you linked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your custom `<Button>` [styled as you want](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#shorthand).

Lets create `<StyledButton>` by overwriting style (padding) of [outlined and large variant of button](https://material-ui.com/api/button/#css).

```
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = {
  outlinedSizeLarge: {
    padding: "6px 21px" // default is "7px 21px" https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L202
  }
};

const StyledButton = withStyles(styles)(Button);
```

Then you can use it in your component:

```
<form onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit(this.state.text)}>
    <TextField id="task" label="Task" placeholder="e.g. Feed the fish" value={this.state.text} onChange={this.handleChange} color="secondary" variant="outlined" size="small"/>
    <StyledButton color="secondary" variant="outlined" endIcon={<AddIcon/>} size="large">Add</StyledButton>
</form>
```

Result:

[image]

Live demo

[image: Edit sad-resonance-u6y9d]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I ended up making up an inline style for my button with a padding-top of 7px and padding-bottom of 8px. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use `variant` attribute with value `outlined`?

```
<Button variant='outlined' size='small'>Add</Button>
```