# Set height of a div dynamically

Tags: javascript, css

I try to adjust the height of a div, based on the height of another div. Looks quite simple.. But unfortunately, it does not work. So please give me a hand in this. Here is my code:

```
   anderblokhoogte = document.getElementById('slider-gaea');
   var curblok = document.getElementById('curiculum');
   curblok.clientHeight = anderblokhoogte.clientHeight + 'px !important';
```

I proved the element 'slider-gaea' exists, but the clientHeight of 'anderblokhoogte' differs from the height I see when inspecting this element. But also, the adjustment of the curblok.clientHeight does not give a change in height of the target element.

I already tried quite some options (other properties like 'style.height', 'offsetHeight') but no idea what mistake I make.

Comment: `clientHeight` is read only, you cannot assign values to it. `The Element.clientHeight read-only property...` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight

Comment: you should use `curblok.style.height = ...`

Comment: Can you give us a [minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see your case ?

Comment: I think you can easily handle it in CSS with flexbox, please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-side-by-side-div-elements-the-same-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
anderblokhoogte = document.getElementById('slider-gaea');
var curblok = document.getElementById('curiculum');
document.getElementById('curiculum').style.height = anderblokhoogte.clientHeight + 'px';
```

```html
<div id="slider-gaea" style="height:100px;"> First Div Block </div>
<div id="curiculum"> Second Div Block</div>
```

You cannot set height using `.clientHeight` instead use `.style.height` and you need to lose the `!important` at the end as well.

[`Element.clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) is a read-only property.

**Note**: While [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#setting_styles) is also a read-only property, it is possible to [set an inline style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#setting_styles) by assigning a string directly to the style property (see example above).

Comment: Yesss, the setting of the curblock height works this way. The special thing is although the 'slider-gaea' has 662px height, the clientheight is given as 466 px. So still both div's do not have the same height .... No idea why (sorry from a newbie)

Comment: clientHeight = height of an element + vertical padding 
Whereas offsetHeight = height of the element + vertical padding + top and bottom borders +  horizontal scrollbar (if it's available). You can try accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately offsetHeight and clientHeight both have the same value. I searched for all kinds of properties with name height in it and also searched for any property holding 662, but no property came up. Perhaps I should point to another div

Comment: Finally I found out that Firefox gives alternative pixelheights if in inspection modus. When I quit the inspectionmodus the pixelheights are as they should be. So problem solved!! Thanks for the help