# Make elements on same line

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

I'm making a blog app using React, Material UI and Tailwindcss.

I made a grid of posts, but every postcard has a different height.

The question is: how to make all cards have the same height and all children in the same line?

Like This:
[image: photo]

My Code:
Posts.jsx:

```js
function Posts({ posts }) {
  return (
    <div className="mt-10">
      <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <Grid
          container
          rowSpacing={8}
          columnSpacing={8}
          direction="row"
          justifyContent="center"
        >
          {posts.map((post, index) => (
            <Grid key={index} item xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={4}>
              <Card>
                <CardActionArea>
                  <div className="flex flex-col ">
                    <CardHeader
                      avatar={
                        <Avatar>{post?.username?.substring(0, 1)}</Avatar>
                      }
                      title={post?.username}
                      subheader={"date"}
                      subheaderTypographyProps={{
                        color: "primary.dark",
                      }}
                      color="primary.main"
                    />
                    <CardMedia
                      component="img"
                      height="194"
                      image={post?.photoURL}
                    />
                    <CardContent>
                      <Typography variant="h6" color="primary.main">
                        {post.description}
                      </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                    <Divider variant="middle" className="bg-[#fcfcfc]" />

                    <CardActions>
                      <IconButton>
                        <MdFavorite className="text-red-500" />
                      </IconButton>
                    </CardActions>
                  </div>
                </CardActionArea>
              </Card>
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Posts;
```

Comment: Try simplifying the code you've provided here down to just the outputted HTML and CSS. This is really just a CSS question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I keep two side-by-side div elements the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-side-by-side-div-elements-the-same-height)

Comment: @Leland I don't have css code just jsx, and no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try targeting the root `<img>` element directly by using the `sx` property. `<CardMedia>` would be updated like this:

```js
    ...
    <CardMedia
        component="img"
        height="194"
        image={post?.photoURL}
        sx={ {
            ['&.MuiCardMedia-root.MuiCardMedia-media.MuiCardMedia-img']: {
                maxHeight: '194px'
            }
        } }
    />
    ...
```

As for making *all children in the same line*, you could:

1. set a **maxHeight** on the `<CardHeader>` and `<CardContent>` components, and
2. if you do not have control over the character length of the text in the header and content, use `overflow: 'hidden'`, and `textOverflow: 'ellipsis'` to prevent long text strings from vertically expanding the `<CardHeader>` and `<CardContent>` components.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a fixed height on your  tag. Also if the size of the images vary for each card it might cause a difference in the height of the whole card. If it doesn't work, try changing the height on your image to height: '194' to height: '194px'. Maybe this is what is causing an error.

Comment: It doesn't work and yes every image has Different size, but i cant fix the size issue because the images is uploaded by the users.